# How to manage a group drive with parameters by default as root url in Laravel4

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

In Laravel 4, i would like manage a route group where my route uri default would be like ?

**user/{id}/{username}**

Because my other url related to my controller user intervene after this url default **/user/{id}/{username}/{other way ...}**

My Controller is within a folder User/ProfileController.php

***My Controller:***

```
namespace User;


class ProfileController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function home()
    {
        // home profile
    }


    public function wall()
    {
        return \View::make('profile.wall');
    }

    public function setting()
    {
        // settings
    }

}
```

***My route is:***

```
Route::get('user/{id}/{username}', 'UserProfileController@wall');
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'user/{id}/{username}'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'UserProfileController@wall');
});
```

And this is just my opinion, but I don't think it's a good idea to put both id and username in the url. Of course, if there is no good reason to do that. This way you're giving too much sensitive info to the user. You should just use the username.

Comment: Yes, simple in fact. Thank you very much.